# Getting into child nodes with php DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I know this has been asked a few times before but I really can't seem to figure it out from other examples on here.

```
    $classname = "gallery2";
    $pageDOM = new DOMDocument();
    $pageDOM->loadHTML($kl);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($pageDOM);
    $ul = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='$classname']");
    $ulNode = $ul->item(0);

    $ulHTML = new DOMDocument();

    $ulHTML->appendChild($ulHTML->importNode($ulNode, TRUE));
    $ulHTMLsaved = $ulHTML->saveHTML();
```

`var_dump` on $ulHTMLsaved returns all the markup that I want, but then how do I do a foreach and get into to a child node from the existing variable that I've set?

`$ulHTMLsaved` contains something like the following & I want to grab various attributes from other nodes nested within all the `li` nodes.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <a>
                <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <a href="">
                <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: DOM's a tree. Every node (e.g. html tag) in that tree is itself the root of a child tree. Once you have xpath find a node for you, you can use that node for further DOM operations.

Comment: So use the same xpath variable and create a new variable using the query? Something like `$xpath->query("//a");` but how do I loop on the `li` nodes?

Comment: use the second arg for query(), which is for "context". e.g. `$xpath->query('//a', $node_from_previous_result)` will restrict xpath's search to the DOM branch of which $node is the "root".

Comment: Ah ok, ok how would I go about setting `$node_from_previous_result`?

Comment: `foreach ($ul as $subnode) { ... ->query('new query', $subnode) }`, basically

Comment: hmm despite adding the context variable it seems to still load a node outside of my context?

Comment: edit*: here's an example of what I'm trying: http://ideone.com/iZkhP5

Comment: @MarcB can you spot what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get into child elements by searching for them with the following:

[getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

[getElementById](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)

There will probably be a more generic one too for classes similar to javascript's `querySelectorAll`, but not sure what that is currently.